# UISearchController iOS 11 Customization

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, ios11

I had been using the following code prior to iOS 11 to customize the appearance of the `UISearchController` search bar:

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.setDefaultSearchBar()
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

extension UISearchBar {
    func setDefaultSearchBar() {
        self.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        self.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        self.backgroundImage = UIImage(color: UIColor.clear)
        let searchBarTextField = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
        searchBarTextField.textColor = UIColor.white
        searchBarTextField.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        searchBarTextField = .dark
    }
}
```

However, the appearance of the search bar fails to update when running the same code on iOS 11.

**iOS 10:**

[image]

**iOS 11:**

[image]

Much of the attention to this question so far has focused on the text color of the search bar. I am looking at more than this - the background color, tint color, the search indicator, clear button color, etc.

Comment: Well asked,  but I cannot be surprised if, when you adopt the notion of the search field being handled through the navigation bar, the runtime imposes its own look upon it. You might be able to enforce your customizations by delaying them until after the runtime has had a chance to configure the search bar itself, but that's just a guess and it wouldn't surprise me if that didn't work either.

Comment: You can achieve that kind of customisation using appearance proxies. However, in my experience it was buggy - The bar looks exactly as I want it to at first, but when another view controller hides it, it loses the rounded corners.

Comment: Try apply font appearance to search field (white font color).

Comment: Try by adding `searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white` It should work.

Comment: Which version of iOS11 are you using? Have you did a complete clean of the Project? It may be a bug of the OS. However I will try to reproduce it and give you feedback soon...!
@NishantBhindi he already does it...

Comment: I am using the latest beta version of iOS 11 @AndreaVultaggio

Comment: try setting the navigationItem textColor

Comment: Post an example project on GitHub, maybe you will get some more help that way.

Comment: I have the same problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997996/ios-11-uisearchbar-in-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 79):

I just found out how to set them: (with some help of Brandon and Krunal, thanks!)

The "Cancel" text:

```
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
```

The search icon:

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_search_icon"), for: UISearchBarIcon.search, state: .normal)
```

The clear icon:

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_search_icon"), for: UISearchBarIcon.clear, state: .normal)
```

The search text:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white]
```

[image]

The placeholder:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

[image]

The white background:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    sc.delegate = self
    let scb = sc.searchBar
    scb.tintColor = UIColor.white
    scb.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    if let textfield = scb.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

            // Background color
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            // Rounded corner
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }

    if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    navigationItem.searchController = sc
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

[image]

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997996/ios-11-uisearchbar-in-uinavigationbar/45999985#comment79464623_45999985).

Comment: Again this answer isn’t great with colors. They navigation bar background color always seems darker than with what you specify.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderMacLeod , did you fix it?

Comment: Should be advised that, like through all of iOS dev, using any `value:forKey:` is considered accessing private api waters and would be most likely against Apple's t&c

Comment: WHY DOES APPLE BREAK THINGS EVERY RELEASE

Comment: This answer has almost saved me! Thanks! The only issue is that when you are pushing between view controllers, a black animated row appears instantly in the background of navigation area.

Comment: @Konstantinos Im having the same issue, did you find a quick fix for this?

Comment: One issue with the white background code: a thin white line appears above the search field when pulling down the tableview. Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: @iruleonu unfortunately  not, if you mean the "black animated row..." issue.

Comment: @Konstantinos it turned out to be the background color of a parent view. (this search bar was on a UIViewController set as a root of a UINavigationController inside of a UITabBarController)

Comment: Another issue is the background color is not white but whiteish. I can't seem to get that changed in any way. Making my own implementation and living without the navigation integration.

Comment: I found a solution for the whiteish. The solution is to use searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal) with an image that is transparent. If anyone need a solution pm me and I'll add it.

Comment: navigationbar.isTranslucent = false  will also need for navigation bar

Comment: Best answer! 
Tried dozens of methods and only this one worked

Answer (score 11):

To properly set the text typed into the search bar to white use (when using a dark field color):

```
searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
```

To set the textfield background color

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

        if let textfield = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

                // Background color
                backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                // Rounded corner
                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

However using something like

```
textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue
```

in the above does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the search bar's bar style.

```
searchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

[image: image 1]

Comment: Excellent! This switches the text colour from black to white.

Answer (score 5):

Moving the call to `setDefaultSearchBar` into `viewDidAppear` should fix this.

Comment: This answer works with some properties like text color but not backgroundImage. It also leaves an ugly snap change when pushing between views

Comment: @AlexanderMacLeod too bad but I guess you are right, it won't work for all props :(

Answer (score 4):

You need to find the `UISearchBar`'s underlying `UITextField` and change its text color.

Notice this only have effect when search controller is going to present (`UISearchControllerDelegate.willPresentSearchController`) or presented.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // setup your search controller...

        // set search controller's delegate
        navigationItem.searchController?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController : UISearchControllerDelegate {

    func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        // update text color
        searchController.searchBar.textField?.textColor = .white
    }
}

extension UISearchBar {

    var textField: UITextField? {
        for subview in subviews.first?.subviews ?? [] {
            if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
                return textField
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day) It is really a challenge to customize UISearchBar in IOS

Answer (score 3):

```
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your answer a little more? Code-only answers are generally not the most useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try it: `searchController.<YOUR SEARCHBAR>.barStyle = .blackOpaque` instead of `self.searchBarStyle = .minimal`.

Thus:

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.setDefaultSearchBar()
//Add this line below
searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

extension UISearchBar {
    func setDefaultSearchBar() {
        self.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        //Delete this line below
        self.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        self.backgroundImage = UIImage(color: UIColor.clear)
        let searchBarTextField = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
        searchBarTextField.textColor = UIColor.white
        searchBarTextField.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        searchBarTextField = .dark
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the background colour of the textField in the searchBar, see my answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46315974/1109892

Comment: Your answer doesn't work particularly well with colours - they always seem much darker than what you specify in code

Comment: Yes I know, but it's the best I could get. Let me know if you find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the UITextField inside the UISearchBar. You can do that by using

```
let textFieldInsideSearchBar = yourSearchbar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField

textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = yourcolor
```

OR

[image]

Comment: Probably You got clear tint color, it's the only reason I could imaging try to set

"_searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];"