# iOS 11 customise search bar in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I want to change the color of the text and icon in the iOS 11 searchbar when it is embedded in the navigation bar. So placeholder text, search text and search icon.

[image]

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Suchen"
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
}
```

As you can see in the image, the text is grey on a deep blue background, which looks ugly. I want to text and icon to be at least white. (changing the blue background color also does not work really good, see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997996/ios-11-uisearchbar-in-uinavigationbar))

The only thing which works is changing the color of the blinking cursor and the "cancel" button, which is done with the .tintColor property.

Solutions which seems to work in iOS 10 and below seem not work anymore in iOS 11, so please post only solutions which you know working in iOS 11. Thanks.

Maybe I miss the point about this "automatic styling" in iOS 11. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted `UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .white` ?

Comment: Yes, does not work.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I just found out how to set also the rest of them: (with some help of Brandon, thanks!)

The "Cancel" text:

```
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
```

The search icon:

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_search_icon"), for: UISearchBarIcon.search, state: .normal)
```

The clear icon:

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_search_icon"), for: UISearchBarIcon.clear, state: .normal)
```

The search text:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white]
```

Thanks for the help @Brandon!

[image]

The placeholder:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

[image]

The white background:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.delegate = self

let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
    textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue
    if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

        // Background color
        backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // Rounded corner
        backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
    }
}

if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
    navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
}

navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

[image]

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997996/ios-11-uisearchbar-in-uinavigationbar/45999985#comment79464623_45999985).

Comment: Awesome stuff, very helpful --- However, I'm having a problem with the background color, the white background of the field. If you sample it, it is not actually white, it's rgb(.95,.95,.95). Turns out, that `textField.subviews.first` view has its own subviews, which apply alpha-tinted shading. I've tried everything short of swizzling to kill those shaders, no luck. If anyone finds a fix, would love to hear it

Comment: Regarding ^^ I finally found a fix. After the search bar `didMoveToSuperview`, if you go `for subview in textField.subviews.first.subviews` `subview.removeFromSuperview()` it seems you can eliminate the shaders, and get a pure white background rgb(1,1,1)

Comment: @beebcon have either of you fixed this on iOS 11.2 where the text when typed is coloured white so is invisible?

Comment: not sure if anyone has come across this, but it seems like the searchbar background color defaults to black unless it is given one of the UIColor enums as a value

Comment: So I have a custom color (it's a shade of gray) and it kept appearing as black. I was going to use the above solution but it removed my custom color altogether (although it wouldn't if I set the background to white...which makes no sense). So I set out to have a bottom border (like material design search bar) since my search bar blended in with the nav bar and all the sudden, BOOM my proper custom gray showed up. Figured out if I set `tf.borderStyle = .none` it magically works. wow.

Comment: To change background color, no need to access a subview, simply do this: `if let textfield = scb.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }`

Comment: Isn't this using private api? Will apple approve this?

Comment: @BrunoMuniz No, it‘s not a private API. But it implies knowledge of the inner workings of the navigation bar. Which means - it could stop working in a future iOS version. So you need to test it on iOS updates.

Comment: as @MichaelMcKenna says, but to keep the rounded corners and the exact color I want, then I needed to first set the borderStyle to .none and then immediately to .roundedRect in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 3):

Put

`UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]`

and

`UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white` in the `AppDelegate`.

Alternatively, put them both in `[UIViewController viewDidLoad:]`

Comment: This, does change the search text color, great! But the placeholder text color and icon is still missing.

Comment: Objective-C syntax:

        [UISearchBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        
        [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]]
         setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Darko's answer.
In my case I need to get pure white search textfield color.
Also I need a custom borderLine and cornerRadius.
So if I just set background color to white, set custom corner radius and custom border line I've got something like this.
[image: Look at this ugly grey highLight when you tap on textfield]

The problem is that the search bar has some subviews and I've just removed them.
Here is my code:

```
@interface YourViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate>
// your properties
@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
_searchController.delegate = self;
_searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
_searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

    UITextField *searchTextField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"searchField"];
if (searchTextField != nil) {
        searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 4.f;
        searchTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
        searchTextField.clipsToBounds = YES;

        for (UIView *subView in searchTextField.subviews) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
}

// Color for "Cancel" button
    _searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
// Add searchController to navgationBar
    _navigationItem.searchController = _searchController;
// Hide searchBar when scroll
    _navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;
}
}
```

Now I've got a searchBar with pure white background, custom cornerRadius, custom border width. Also I've disabled grey highlight when tap.
[image: Editing searchfield]
[image: Resign first responder]

Comment: How did you disable the grey highlight when tapped?

Comment: @AndrewMorris Look in the code above. There is a loop in which i delete subviews of 'searchTextField.subviews'

Answer (score 2):

Set Search Text Color

```
(UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]) ).defaultTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Set Search Placeholder Color

```
(UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]) ).attributedPlaceholder = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: This one is great for the Search Text Color. Why does the solution to Change the Background not work for me?

Answer (score 1):

my two cents for Swift 4.x, lightly cleaned up.

Add in controller or App Delegate:

```
appearance.backgroundColor = .green
let myFont = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
let attribs = [
    NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue): myFont,
    NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.red
]

appearance.defaultTextAttributes =  attribs
```

in controller:

```
self.searchBar.barTintColor = .blue
```

You  will get Blue background, green search bar background, red italic font:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to mention how is `appearance` declared.

Comment: right! //search bar:
        let appearance = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])

Answer (score 0):

I tried Daroko solution, but i had a problem when changing the background to pure white color (it’s was grey).
My **solution** was to use the **setSearchFieldBackgroundImage**. also i don't want to rely on apple struct for getting the UITextField

```
  if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     let whiteImage = UIImage(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: searchController.searchBar.layer.frame.width, height: searchController.searchBar.layer.frame.height))
     searchController.searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(whiteImage, for: .normal)
     self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
     self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
 }


public extension UIImage {
  public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
     color.setFill()
     UIRectFill(rect)
     let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
     self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
} }
```

I used UIImage extension from :
[Create UIImage with solid color in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets stuck wondering why [Darkos solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46010398/3748535) doesn't work, try changing the UINavigationBar's style to `default` instead of `black`. Took me half a day to figure out ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -4):

This code changes the background color of the text field

**Swift 4**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //background color of text field
         UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .cyan

        }
```

edited: sample of a UISearchBar in cyan

[image: sample]

Comment: Does not work. Or is there something that I might be missing?

Comment: Does not work for UISearchController, perhaps it works for UISearchBar

Comment: I tried again and this line of code still works for me, I edited my reply with a screenshot. This is iOS 11