# iOS 11 UISearchBar background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar, ios11

I understand that this question has been asked many, **many** times on SO. However, as Apple does best, with the release of **iOS 11**, they seem to have made a seemingly unnecessary change to the `UISearchBar`, specifically it's view hierarchy.

In further, the "text field" of a search bar is no longer accessible in the search bar's subviews, causing **all** of the previous solutions to "access" and change the background color of the text field, or any property of the text field for that matter.

- Does anyone know how to **actually** adjust the background color of a search bar in **iOS 11**?

**FYI:**
I am specifically talking about the color behind the text... which now as of 11 defaults to white unless you specify the search bar style to be minimal.

**UPDATE 1:**

Since my posting of this question, I still have not found a valid or really *any* **real solution** to this issue. The closest I have seem to come is to dive deep into the appearance for instance properties

```
[[UISearchBar class] appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:(nonnull NSArray<Class<UIAppearanceContainer>> *)]
```

of the `UISearchBar`. Playing around with the found `UITextField` via methods such as the following:

```
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    return (UITextField*)view;
}
UITextField *searchTextField;
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    searchTextField = [self searchViewForTextFieldBg:subview];
    if (searchTextField) {
        break;
    }
}
return searchTextField;
```

you can begin drawing a **new** background view to be placed behind the view. However, the issues I had found too tedious to pursue further were drawing the a view with the correct frame / bounds to mimic exactly the original background.

Hopefully someone can find the *actual* solution to this problem. Nice miss apple...

Comment: Have you tried UIView.appearance(whenContainedIn: UISearchBar)? Just an idea

Comment: Have you seen this Q&A? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46010398/968219

Comment: @OscarApeland yes, tried many things including appearanceWhenCont... but nothing..

Comment: @zgosalvez yes, but to override the white background that answer suggests `let textfield = scb.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField` which I believe is against Apple's t&c since that's technically accessing a private API no?

Comment: @WillVonUllrich This isn't strictly disallowed, but it's unsafe as iOS updates can break undocumented features. It might be counted as using private APIs as well, but I've had an app in production with that exact hack without problems.

Comment: Gotcha - good to know you have a prod app with this, but ... is there really no other way to do this? lol pretty sad

Comment: how can apple release an ios version where it is impossible to set the bar tint color....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you may be looking for this, right? But I've it in Swift :(

```
@IBOutlet weak var sbSearchBar: UISearchBar!

if let textfield = sbSearchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
    textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue
    textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: This will work you're right - I was more or less hoping for a solution relative to apples non-private api's. Of course this *does* work, it's just frowned upon as it runs the risk of failing at any point in the future from an update from apple

Comment: This worked for text color but not background color

Answer (score 10):

This Swift code changes the background color of the text field:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
    // background color of text field
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .cyan        
}
```

This is the result

[image: example used to change the background to cyan color]

Comment: Sadly I have not been able to get this to work (as stated in my OP comments)

Comment: This worked for me after Apple randomly stopped displaying my selected background color.

Answer (score 7):

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect())
let searchField: UITextField? = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
let searchBarBackground: UIView? = searchBar.value(forKey: "background") as? UIView
// searchBarBackground?.removeFromSuperview()

if searchField != nil {
    var frame = searchField?.frame
    frame?.size.height = 30
    searchField?.frame = frame!
    searchField?.backgroundColor = .yellow
}

searchBar.barTintColor = .red
searchBar.delegate = self
searchBar.backgroundColor = .green
```

#### Runtime Views Hierarchy

If we set background colors for UISearchBar with code above, we'll see the colored subviews as follow images(click links to see).
￼

#### `backgroundColor` for Superview of UISearchBar subviews

We can see the Class Name of green view is **UISearchBar** in **Object inspector**.

So, if we use `searchBar.backgroundColor = .green`, we'll set the backgroundColor of Superview green. Therefore, the UISearchBar instance property `backgroundColor` will set the superview's background color.

[Superview of UISearchBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMfNY.jpg)

#### `barTintColor` for UISearchBarBackground

We can see the Class Name of red view is **UISearchBarBackground** in **Object inspector**.

However, there's no direct method to access the view, we can use **KVC** `searchBar.value(forKey: "background") as? UIView` try to get **searchBarBackground**.

If we use `searchBar.barTintColor = .red`, we'll set the backgroundColor of UISearchBarBackground's view red. **In order to remove two black border on the tint bar layer, we have to remove the background from superview.**

[barTintColor of UISearchBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv8Ti.jpg)

#### `searchField?.backgroundColor` for UITextField

We can see the Class Name of yellow view is **_UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView** (Subview of UISearchBarTextField) in Object inspector.

There's no direct method to access the **searchField**, same as *searchBarBackground*. We can also use **KVC** `searchField: UITextField? = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField` try to get **searchField**.

If we use `searchField?.backgroundColor = .yellow`, we'll set the backgroundColor of UITextField yellow. Therefore, if we want to set text field background color, we have to access the searchField with **KVC** first

[UITextField of UISearchBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRJJW.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please explain how this code would help the OP.

Comment: Sorry, it’s my first time to answer question on stackoverflow and I am inexperienced about it  , so I haven’t written why it works. I will capture the hierarchy of my App during debug runtime and explain how it helps tomorrow. : ) — ignore my English grammatical errors ,from a Chinese girl thanks~ 囧

Answer (score 4):

It's much simpler than that in Swift 5.

```
    searchBar.barTintColor = .black
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: Note that `searchTextField` is only available after iOS 13

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4-5**

`searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .white`