# UISearchController searchBar background color of text field in iOS 11

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I want to change the background color of a text field in `searchBar` embedded in UISearchController in iOS 11, using the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
private var searchController: UISearchController!
    
    private var data: [String] = []
    
    private var filtered: [String] = []
    
    private var tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for i in 1...100 {
            self.data.append("row \(i)")
        }
        self.filtered = data
        
        let src = SearchResultController()
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: src)
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = src
        
        self.searchController.searchBar.textField?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.37, blue:0.53, alpha:1)
        
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.searchController.showsSearchResultsController = true
        }
        self.navigationItem.title = "Search"
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController

        self.setupNavigationBar()
        self.setupTableView()
        
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }
}
```

So when I write code like this

```
self.searchController.searchBar.textField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.37, blue:0.53, alpha:1)
```

nothing has changed.

when I write

```
self.searchController.searchBar.textField?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.37, blue:0.53, alpha:1)
```

I have something like this. The problem is that textfiled is too dark.

[image]

And when I write this. Alpha = 0.5

```
self.searchController.searchBar.textField?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.37, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
```

I have this. And this is what I want.

[image]

So my question is what I'm doing wrong ? And what the proper method to set background color of the textfiled in search bar embedded in UISearchController ?

Comment: Did you try setting `barTintColor` like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384000/3734028

Comment: Yes I've tried to do it. It's not working.