# Why can't I set the textcolor of searchbar in iOS11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11

I use this in an earlier version to get the textfield in my searchBar...

```
UITextField *searchField = [self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
```

In iOS11, it's still worked, I can change the text、font、even tintcolor，but I just can't set the textcolor, please teach me.

```
UISearchController *mySearchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
mySearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.navigationItem.searchController = mySearchController;
```

//    mySearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;

```
self.tableView.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.tableView.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.navigationItem.title = @"xxxx";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"reload" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refresh)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;

UITextField *txfSearchField = [self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
txfSearchField.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];

//this code is no use
txfSearchField.textColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

txfSearchField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
UIView *backgroundview= [[txfSearchField subviews]firstObject ];
backgroundview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISearchBar text color change in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048766/uisearchbar-text-color-change-in-ios-7)

Comment: @brandonscript NO, the satuation is different

Comment: UISearchController _searchField is private API, so you can't use it safely. 
Maybe changing color does'nt work since iOS 11 because the textField has an attributedText set. 
Try to replace txfSearchField.attributedText.

Comment: @vmeyer Thanks for answering, but stil no use.I can change the text this way ,but  can't change the textcolor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally find the way, write like this:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]}];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setAttributedPlaceholder:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor orangeColor]}]];
```

Answer (score 6):

In swift, you can try:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red]
```

I find this answer here: [iOS 11 customise search bar in navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007260/ios-11-customise-search-bar-in-navigation-bar)

Also tried direct set `defaultTextAttributes` of `txfSearchField` to `[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red]` will not change the text color. But change `backgroundColor` will work, do not know why.

Answer (score 2):

Tony's answer works great. Here is the Swift 5-Version for these lines:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange])
```