# How does Apple implement scrolling up a UIScrollView until the navigation bar with large title and UISearchBar appear?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to replicate the behavior of `scrollsToTop` property on `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` -

If you tap the status bar the scroll view scrolls up to the top and shows the full height of the navigation bar with the large title and also slowly scrolls to show the `UISearchBar` embedded into the navigation item.

Sample project [here](https://github.com/aakhedr/Scroll)

The scroll view scrolls up to the top fine but I cannot get it to show the the search bar if its `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` is set to `true`

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to emulate the behavior of the Settings and Mail apps in iOS 11? Not all apps do this.

Comment: Does the code in the question here give you a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46007260/5496433

Comment: If `scrollsToTop` is left to `true` on any scroll view, and a user taps on the status bar, behavior is the same on any app like Settings and Mail...

Comment: not really @BallpointBen