# UISearchController/SearchBar in Navigation Controller

Tags: swift

I have a TableView with simple data in it. I have added SearchBar to the Navigation controller by code. (Not sure have i done proper way or not, but it is working). This is how it looks:

**Code is below:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var data = ["Hello","This","Is","Table","View","With","Search","Bar","Included","In","NavBar","But","SearchBar","Is","Not","Done","Properly"]
    var filtered = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //My original array and filtered arrays.
        filtered = data
        // Here a play with preferences add/delete 
        let searchBar = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.searchController = searchBar
       navigationItem.searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        navigationItem.searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filtered.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            filtered = data
        }
        else {
            filtered = data.filter  {$0.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())}
            }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

As you see i have done it by creating SearchController and then adding it to a NavController. 
Also implemented delegate **UISearchResultsUpdating** method to search and filter.

I have tried several ways but i do not know how to access to properties of SearchBar and NavController. (not by storyboard)

Some screenshots:

[image][image]

After like a day of search and try, i am not actually sure about it, as some methods work but some not. As example:

**This works:**

```
navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = .white
```

**This does not work:**

```
navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.barTintColor = .red
```

So why can i access to one property and cannot to other? 
It is a very simple functionality, but tricky to find.

Maybe you could provide me some resource i could use for my case, as indicated in Images? 
Or if you have a time - some solution, maybe root example.

Thanks in advance.

Will continue to search.

Comment: Does this answer help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007260/ios-11-customise-search-bar-in-navigation-bar

Comment: Thanks for link and efforts. Yes, some how i have managed to fix some of the cases, but not yet understood how to change background. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can do that with setBackgroundImage and just use a colour value.

Comment: You mean that i can add image to SearchBar to make its searchField white?

Comment: It's a long time since i needed to this, some UI elements you can change background colour using an image created from a colour. try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751292/cannot-change-search-bar-background-color

Comment: I have somehow managed almost to achieve what i want by your first link. thanks.