# Change UISearchBar background image in iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to change my UISearchBar background image.
When adding it as the header view in my UITableView it works perfectly fine. However, when I want to change it for the SearchBar being set as the searchController of the navigationItem it won´t change the background image.

I´m using:

```
self.searchBar.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "#IMAGENAME")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for this:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "pattern")!)
    }
    navigationItem.searchController = sc
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

Here is image:

[image]

And here is result:

[image]

Here is more detailed answer, if you want to change any other UI elements of search bar.

- [iOS 11 UISearchBar in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997996/ios-11-uisearchbar-in-uinavigationbar/45999985#45999985)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for this answer for a long time!

Comment: For those who have Search Bar in the Navigation Bar try Replacing : `navigationItem.searchController = sc` *with ->*  `navigationItem.titleView = sc.searchBar`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below Code I have used the similar One :

// Objective-c Code

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor yourColor]] 
                                         forBarPosition:0 
                                             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

// Swift Code

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(self.image(colo
r: UIColor.yourColor), for: UIBarPosition(rawValue: 0)!, barMetrics:.default)
```

Please let me know the result

Comment: Op asked for UISearchController in UINavigationItem, not the deprecated UISearchDisplayController.