# Use background image on UISearchController iOS 11

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm implementing an `UISearchController` to my `UITableView` but I'm struggling with the customization for iOS 11. My navigation bar is using a gradient image background that I want the search controller to match, but I haven't found a way to set the background image for `UISearchController`. It works perfectly on UISearchController as a TableHeaderView, but in iOS 11 barely any customization is passed on.

**Current outcome:**

[image: Current outcome]

**Desired outcome:**

[image: Desired outcome]

**This is the code I'm using:** *(called on viewDidLoad)*

```
private func setupSearchController() {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    // Convert CAGradientLayer to UIImage
    let gradient = Color.blue.gradient
    gradient.frame = searchController.searchBar.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradient.bounds.size)
    gradient.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Setup the Search Controller
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = gradientImage
    searchController.searchBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by transaction name"
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = Color.custom(hexString: "FAFAFA", alpha: 1).value
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    // Implement Search Controller
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(gradientImage, for: .default)
    } else {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }

}
```

Comment: What is Color.blue.gradient?

Comment: Long time ago, but I believe I used a custom Color class. I think Color.blue.gradient is of type `CAGradientLayer`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Krunal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204211/7776268) I was able to find a decent solution after searching for quite some time.

This is how I came about implementing the background-image for iOS 11:

```
    // Implement Search Controller
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage!)
        }
        if let textField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            if let backgroundview = textField.subviews.first {
                backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;

            }
        }
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    } else {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

Comment: Is there  a way to apply this method for vertical gradient. While applying it is coming as two sections for searchBar and navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CustomView for this. 
Use CustomView to add your searchBar to it, and then add this customView to your ViewController.
Now you can easily set the background of this customView as:

```
//if customView is named as customView

    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background.png")
    self.customView.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I would regard this as more of a hack than a solution, there should really be a way to customize standard implementation of a UISearchController

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5, iOS 15**

Considering `searchController` is a property of your class (vc most likely), navigation vc is not nil, "gradient" image is your asset with a gradient mix of some colors.
Put this code in your `viewDidLoad` to achieve a gradient navigation bar and a search field with a white background color.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "gradient")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero,
                                                                        resizingMode: .stretch)
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance

searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

/// Trick to have a white searchTextField background color, weird but it works.
searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white

navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Result:
[image]

Moving back from current vc you may want to reset your navigation bar to the default settings. For this purpose you may try to create `UINavigationViewController` extension with a handy function:

```swift
extension UINavigationController {

    func resetToDefaultAppearance() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()

        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Then call it in your `viewWillDisappear`:

```swift
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    navigationController?.resetToDefaultAppearance()
}
```