# Add space between navigationBar and searchBar - Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I use some classical `UInavigationBar` and `UISearchController` at head of a `UICollectionView`.
My searchController is sticked to my navigationBar as I can scroll into my collectionView and use my searchController at any moment.

I'd like to know if there is a way to add space between my `UInavigationBar` and `UISearchController` as described in screenshot below :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this in your storyboard if you have one, just select your searchbar and define constraints with the constraint icon (it looks like a square with two bars on each sides). Tell me if you still have the problem.

Comment: I'm doing it programmatically :(

Comment: Can you post your code? It should include your view controller class where you have your navigation bar and searchbar defined

Comment: I think I found another solution... instead of trying modify build-in swift components and add too many constraints for a same behaviour, I prefer try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377722/use-background-image-on-uisearchcontroller-ios-11/48444177