# How make UISearchbar rectangular shape and merge with navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Hello I'm trying to change the UISearchbar to rectangular shape rather then rounded rectangular and merge it with the navigation bar with same color.

[image]

The background color of the navigation bar should be the same as the background of the search bar but there's difference and also there's a clear edge shown both should show the background color #be1b25 and not the #bc303a. As well the textfield still showing rounded rectangle and not fully rectangle.

The Main View Controller code

```
   @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: REDCOLOR)
    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: REDCOLOR)
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: REDCOLOR)
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: REDCOLOR)
    searchBar.barStyle = .default
    searchBar.placeholder = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.language(key: "searchentirestore")
    searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    searchBar.clipsToBounds = false;
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: REDCOLOR)
    searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
    //searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear as! CGColor
```

The UISearchBar Extension

```
extension UISearchBar {

    private var textField: UITextField? {
        return subviews.first?.subviews.flatMap { $0 as? UITextField }.first
    }

    private var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView? {
        return textField?.leftView?.subviews.flatMap{ $0 as? UIActivityIndicatorView }.first
    }

    var isLoading: Bool {
        get {
            return activityIndicator != nil
        } set {
            if newValue {
                if activityIndicator == nil {
                    let newActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
                    newActivityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
                    newActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
                    newActivityIndicator.color = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: BUTTON_COLOR)
                    newActivityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    textField?.leftView?.addSubview(newActivityIndicator)
                    let leftViewSize = textField?.leftView?.frame.size ?? CGSize.zero
                    newActivityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: leftViewSize.width/2, y: leftViewSize.height/2)
                }
            } else {
                activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help please, this is Swift 3. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

so there a few things you are dealing with

## 1 Rectangular `UISearchbar`

- either you will traverse subviews of native `UISearchbar` and change its right sublayers corner radiuses, but this is a **hack**, Apple can change that hierarchy and you will be at the beginning again
- you can create your own component that will look like `UISearchbar`, few UIViews, and `UITextfield` with some UIImageViews.
- there are few libraries on GitHub you can use https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples
- there is also a similar question here [iOS 11 UISearchBar in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997996/ios-11-uisearchbar-in-uinavigationbar)

## 2 Merge with NavBar

- one way is to use `UISearchController` with iOS 11
- or you can with your custom UISearchbar you can either add it below the NavBar in `UIView`, not in navigation, but the **NavBar cannot be translucent** in this case, because **you will never achieve the same color space**
- you can add your custom view as custom `UIView` into `titleView` in NavBar

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend the **UISearchBar** and apply the customization.
2. Set the **UISearchBar** as titleView to the NavigationController

   ```
      class SearchField: UISearchBar {
           override init(frame: CGRect) {
               super.init(frame: frame)
               // Corner radius
               self.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
               self..clipsToBounds = true

               // Textfield inside color.
               if let searchTextField = self.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField {
                   // Set TextField property 
                   // Set the corner radius for TextField (not suggested)

                   if let clearButton = searchTextField.value(forKey: "_clearButton") as? UIButton {
                       // Set the clear button property
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       // Use it in the ViewController.
       let searchBar = SearchField()
       self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
   ```